# Two opposing faces on the x axis turn out dark, almost black in my material

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm trying to create a turtoise shell material for some glasses but the two opposing faces on the x axis turn out dark, almost black.

The material is a variation of one I found in the forums.

The dark face and the material
[image: the dark face and the materia]

The image shows the dark face and the nodes used to obtain the material

[image: the image shows the dark face and the nodes used to obtain the material]

Comment: It may be that your object is so long, and your camera angle is such that a ray cast from the camera doesn't escape the object within the default number of bounces.  Refer this video:  https://youtu.be/Sv2wqwsvx-8?t=201

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: yeah, it seems to have almost fixed itself, i'm gonna be sharing the material if i can, but i'm not shure if i have time,

Comment: @AllenSimpson i'll look into that, thanks